# How does the nexus 2 to 3 migration incrementally detect changes?

Tags: migration, nexus, sonatype

I performed a test migration of my nexus 2 to 3 and after the nexus 3 migration step completed (waiting for the "continue" to finalize) I deployed a new artifact to one of our site repositories on the nexus 2 instance and the nexus 3 upgrade never picked up that change.

Is there some specific mechanism artifacts have to be deployed for it to be picked up?
For the site repo, I didn't use the web-api but just transferred the file to the repo filesystem and refreshed the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the site repo, I didn't use the web-api but just transferred the
>   file to the repo filesystem and refreshed the index.

Changing things on the file system while upgrade is running will not work. Changes will only be detected if you publish the artifact into Nexus via HTTP via standard deployment mechanisms.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked with a web-api deployment.  The change was detected and migrated as well.  Thanks for answer.